# how to filter dates from array of object in mongoose with aggregate

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
  Sellers.aggregate([{ $unwind: "$deal" }, {
            $match: {

                "deal.date": {
                    $lt: "2021-12-11T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                    $gt: "2021-06-11T00:00:00.000+00:00"
                }
            }
        }]).then(docs => {
            console.log(docs)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This is the code that i have been trying on but it shows empty result even there is some actual data which i am looking for in the given specified date .

```
var sellers = new Schema({
name: String,
deal: [{
    orderid: String,
    date: Date,
    bags: Number,
    kilogram: Number,


}]
```

});

this my mongoose instance

Comment: You need to use Date types in the query, not string.

Comment: actually i use date types. I gave it as demonstration